# Google maps embed not zooming

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-embed

I have a strange problem, the google map I added to the map is zoomed out all the way and I can't find out why.

The page in question is at https://workland.ca/en/ then you go to the footer of the site and click contact. Below is the iframe I used. I tried the &z=15 with no effect.

```
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2795.9215847167884!2d-73.56997780251234!3d45.51165713370363!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4cc91a4bbe13b0df%3A0xc06c2aa42d3df87c!2s51+Rue+Sherbrooke+O%2C+Montr%C3%A9al%2C+QC+H2X+1X2!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1419350169105&z=15" 
                        style="width:100%;height:230px; border:0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Just another detail
the map works fine if I show the modal in this way,

```
$(function () {
      $('#modalContact').modal('show');
    })
```

oddly enough after the page loads and I click

```
 <a onclick=" $('#modalContact').modal('show')" href="#">Contact</a>
```

the map is zoomed out again

I found the solution iframe must be loaded after modal is shown

```
<script>
    $(
        function() {
            $('#modalContact').on('shown.bs.modal',
                function() {
                    $(this)
                        .find("#the_map")
                        .html(' <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2795.9215847167884!2d-73.56997780251234!3d45.51165713370363!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4cc91a4bbe13b0df%3A0xc06c2aa42d3df87c!2s51+Rue+Sherbrooke+O%2C+Montr%C3%A9al%2C+QC+H2X+1X2!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1419350169105&z=20" style="width:100%;height:230px; border:0" frameborder="0"></iframe>')
                }
            )
        }
    )
</script>
```

Comment: I believe its &zoom=15 instead of &z=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out that zoom problem raised because of iframe get loaded before 
bootstrap model show method call

You can solve it like follow:
  1) take iframe content in variable

```
    <script>
    var htm ='<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2795.9215847167884!2d-73.56997780251234!3d45.51165713370363!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4cc91a4bbe13b0df%3A0xc06c2aa42d3df87c!2s51+Rue+Sherbrooke+O%2C+Montr%C3%A9al%2C+QC+H2X+1X2!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1419350169105&amp;zoom=1" style="width:100%;height:230px; border:0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
</script>
```

2 ) take one div in modal-body with width and height fixed and greater than ifrmae width and height like

```
<div style="width:500px;height:250px;" class="container">                          
 </div>
```

3 ) on contact click you have to show popup first and then fill up container with iframe like :

```
 <a onclick=" $('#modalContact').modal('show');$('.container').html(htm);" href="#">Contact</a>

And your issue can solve.
```

Comment: Yup that is what is was

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2795.9215847167884!2d-73.56997780251234!3d45.51165713370363!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4cc91a4bbe13b0df%3A0xc06c2aa42d3df87c!2s51+Rue+Sherbrooke+O%2C+Montr%C3%A9al%2C+QC+H2X+1X2!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1419350169105&zoom=15" style="width:100%;height:230px; border:0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```